# Laravel break up paginated eloquent query

Tags: laravel

I currently have:

```
$comments = $this->post->comments()
    ->where('comment', 'like', "%{$search}%")
    ->paginate(50);
```

But I'd like to do something like the below, as I have multiple filters that I'm going to apply:

```
$comments = $this->post->comments();

if(condition)
{
    $comments->where('comment', 'like', "%{$search}%");
}

$comments->paginate();
```

But the code above doesn't work as I then get errors on things like `$comments->links()` for pagination links in the view, indicating that this doesn't work.

Comment: You can use `$this->post->query()` and start chaining from there.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is something like this, I don't know what Laravel version you are using, also I don't know the structure you have of your models, but here's the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) about this example:

```
$conditions = 1;
$comments = Post::with('comments')
                ->whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ($conditions){
                      // pass your conditions
                      if(!$conditions){
                          $query->where('comment', 'like', "%%")
                      }
                      // more conditions, etc
                      $query->where('comment_id', 'like', '%%');
                 })->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was missing `$comment =` in front of the query clauses:

```
$comments = $this->post->comments();

if(condition)
{
    $comments = $comments->where('comment', 'like', "%{$search}%");
}

$comments = $comments->paginate();
```